# accidental flags

Tags: support

I flagged an answer, but then realised I shouldn't have done (I flagged it as not an answer, but there was actually a valid answer buried in the text). There didn't seem to be any way to withdraw the flag, though. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mechanism to withdraw the flag.
When it comes up for moderation, the moderator can accept or reject it.
On accepting it your flag weight is increased appropriately.